# Вставная конструкция

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, вставная-конструкция

"Скорее всего, сын у него был либо единственный() — а значит, любимый —() либо беспечный, раз отец так сильно хотел преподать урок жизни".

Скажите, пожалуйста, как здесь оформить вводную конструкцию с тире? Потому что я сомневаюсь, ставить до и после нее запятые или нет.

Answer (score 0):

*Скорее всего, сын у него был либо единственный — а значит, любимый, — либо беспечный, раз отец так сильно хотел преподать урок жизни.*

Посмотрим на предложение без вставки:

*Скорее всего, сын у него был либо единственный, либо беспечный, раз отец так сильно хотел преподать урок жизни*.

Запятая на месте вставки стоит — значит, еë нужно поставить либо до, либо после вставки, то есть сохранить еë.

Нужно поставить после вставки (т. е. перед вторым тире), т. к. вставная конструкция относится к предыдущей части — следовательно, их нельзя друг от друга отделять. Но запятую ставить нужно, поэтому сохраняем ее и ставим после вставки:

*Скорее всего, сын у него был либо единственный — а значит, любимый, — либо беспечный, раз отец так сильно хотел преподать урок жизни*.